# How do I prove that limit by definition?

Tags: limits, definition, infinity

How do I prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{6n^2-8}{n^2-8}\right)=6$, by definition?
I need to find $N_{\epsilon}$ such that for every $n>N_{\epsilon}$:
$$\left|\left(\frac{6n^2-8}{n^2-8}\right)-6\right|<\epsilon.$$
How do I find the $N_{\epsilon}$?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'definition'...but I think you can divide num and den by $n^2$ and then put $\frac{1}{n}$ as $t$ so that $t \to 0$

Comment: well I started by: |\left(\frac{6n^2-8}{n^2-8}\right)-6\right|=|\left(\frac{6n^2-8-6n^2+48}{n^2-8}\right)\right|=|\left(\frac{40}{n^2-8}\right)\right|

Comment: That should be in your question, not a comment below it. (However, dollar signs around MathJax still work in comments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of question, it is usually helpful to **pretend** that you have already had the desired inequality, and you solve the threshold out of the inequality.

Namely, you want to find $N_\varepsilon$ such that 
$$ \left|\left(\frac{6n^2-8}{n^2-8}\right)-6\right|<\varepsilon, $$ whenever $n>N_\varepsilon$.

Now, just try to separate $n$ and let us assume $n>2$:
\begin{align}
\left|\left(\frac{6n^2-8}{n^2-8}\right)-6\right|<\varepsilon &\iff \left|\frac{40}{n^2-8}\right|<\varepsilon\\
&\iff n^2-8>\frac{40}{\varepsilon}\\
&\iff n^2>8+\frac{40}{\varepsilon}.
\end{align}
Thus, you can just take $$ N_\varepsilon=\left\lfloor\sqrt{8+\frac{40}{\varepsilon}}\right\rfloor+1 $$
and we are done.

Comment: first of all, thank you so much for the help. secondlly your N referring the expression without the absolute value and so how can I show between the  and the expression in the absolute value that it is true or at least demanding on the N also that n>2?

Comment: @mathmagic I have edited my answer. Yes, we should assume that $n>2$.